# How scp between two Oracle Linux machines with localhost.localdomain hostnames

Tags: linux, ssh, hostname

How to `scp` between two Oracle Linux 7.6 machines on virtualbox that have the hostnames `localhost.localdomain`

`scp -r test.txt oracle@localhost:/home/oracle/Desktop/` isn't working.

When I changed the hostname and did `scp -r test.txt oracle@oracle2:/home/oracle/Desktop/` I got the error `ssh: Could not resolve hostname oracle2: name or service not known
lost connection`

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

if you don't have an alias in hosts file, or DNS entry for `oracle2`, this will never work.

you can either:

1. use box IP

```
scp -r test.txt oracle@1.1.1.1:/home/oracle/Desktop/
```

2. set up custom entry in `/etc/hosts` for `oracle2`

edit `/etc/hosts` on `localhost` machine and add:

```
1.1.1.1 oracle2
```

3. add rule to your ssh custom file (`~/.ssh/config`) to specify alias for the box:

```
Host oracle2
  HostName 1.1.1.1
```

4. use bash variable before scp command: `oracle2=1.1.1.1`

Where `1.1.1.1` is oracle2 IP.

Comment: Can you explain how I to do it?

Comment: I've edited my reply